# Can "hold on" and "hold off" be used interchangeably?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

These are two different words but I've often seen them used interchangeably in various situations. For example:

1. I cannot hold off the fort any longer than this.
2. I will hold on to my faiths and beliefs whatever happens.
3. Let's hold on for some time, this draft isn't needed this very moment.

Comment: 'Hold off the fort' doesn't make sense. A fort would hold off an attack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question.

Holding something *off* is generally keeping it away. Holding off or holding back the enemy's attack. Holding *on to* is keeping it close by, preserving it carefully. Holding on to your closely held beliefs. There is also holding *out* as in your number 3. They should be holding *out* for more time they need. They are holding *on to* the slim chance for getting more time. I hope they get it.

Comment: Yes, they're similar and you could mistake them: you can "put a hold on something" which means to stop it, or you can "hold off something" which means to stop it. But as Elliot says, they're not interchangable. A dictionary is your friend.

Comment: I still looking for the list of uses for each of "up, off, in, out, over, etc." Should make quite a show.